# how to place the cursor position after the prefix ,on focus in EditText

Tags: android

How to place the cursor in `EditText` box after the prefix when on focus in android?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need the length of text to perform.

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
edit_text.setSelection(edit_text.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to know how to set cursor position. If the prefix is auto-filled you have some options that make sense. My suggestion is to use `setSelection(position)`.

Example

```
int position = prefix.length(); // take the length of your prefix (String)
editText.setSelection(position);
```

Add an onFocusListener and put the above code inside of it.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

You can always set the cursor position using setSelection(). Here are some other examples.

Below code is an example to set cursor to the starting position in EditText:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
 editText.setSelection(0);
```

Below code is an example to set cursor to end position of the EditText:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```